# run scrapy runspider without the printed logs

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm executing a scrapy spider using:

```
scrapy runspider my_spider.py -o results.json
```

How do I execute it silently, i.e., without all the spider print logs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the command line option `--nolog` which sets `LOG_ENABLED` to `False`

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I was looking for. Btw, in my spider I'm using selenium to open a bowser and scrap from there. Do you know can I also silence the browser itself?

Answer (score 3):

Another answer would be to add the log settings into your settings.py. Which is a bit different than the exact original question.

Info here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html

My code for logs will make it export to a logfile in the folder. It will run silent in terminal but show anything thats NOT DEBUG in the logfile. So you can track it if you want.

```
LOG_ENABLED = True
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO' # Levels: CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG
LOG_FILE = 'logfile.log'
```

This will also make it so that you dont have to attach the --no-log when executing